# ReWrite rule for files of a previously standalone blog moved to network

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, multisite

A moved a standalone wordpress install to be one of a network, but the possibility to access the uploaded files with the same URL is need to be kept.

I'm trying to get the following rewrite rule to work, without success:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)?domain\.com
RewriteRule ^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ /wp-content/blogs.dir/3/files/$1 [L]
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found it by testing all of the combinations, I could imagine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)domain\.com
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ wp-content/blogs\.dir/3/files/$1 [L]
```